# Simplest Linked List Creation and Printing Data

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, data-structures, linked-list

The following is a simple code segment in C to create a linked list and print all elements contained in the list.

User is asked to input integer data till a zero is entered which marks the termination of user input; Once data is saved in the linked list, the program prints all elements stored in the list and then completes its execution.

*I can't make it run, every time it gives a "Segmentation fault" error, please check and tell me where I'm wrong* (using gcc 4.8.2)

Code :

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
};

struct node * createLinkedList() 
{
    int x;
    struct node * start;
    start = NULL;
    printf("Input 0 to end, Insert elements :\n");

for(scanf("%d", &x); x ;scanf("%d", &x))
{
    struct node * temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (temp)
    {
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(start == NULL) {
            start = temp;
        } else {
            start->next = temp;
            start = temp;
        }
    }
}   

return start;
}

void printLinkedList(struct node * start)
{
    if (start == NULL) {
        printf("Linked List is empty!\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nPrinting Linked List : \n");
        struct node * s;
        s = start;
        while(s != NULL) 
        {
            printf("%d\n", s->data);
            s = s->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct node * start;
    start = NULL;
    start = createLinkedList();
    printLinkedList(start);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just look at the for loop... omg

Comment: changed it to *while(x != 0)* + added *scanf("%d", &x)* at appropriate places; **No Change in O/p**

Comment: Use your friendly, neihbourhood debugger, (or gdb), and tell us, (and yourself), which line generates the exception.  It's much easier for you to do it, rather than us, because you have the code, environment etc. already in front of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code

```
    if(start == NULL) {
        start = temp;
    } else {
        start->next = temp;
        start = temp;
    }
```

is invalid. There has to be

```
    if(start == NULL) {
        start = temp;
    } else {
        temp->next = start;
        start = temp;
    }
```

Also you need to have a function that deletes all nodes of the list.